# mandatory checkboxes JSF

Tags: jsf, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes, so I have 3 different IDs. I need at least one checkbox checked by the user. I have defined an error message only for the first ID, so if the user leaves all 3 checkboxes unchecked, he will see my error message and the first checkbox will be marked yellow.

Now I want to mark all 3 checkboxes yellow when none is checked. This is possible with 3 error messages for each ID. But the unwanted side effect is that the users then sees 3 error messages. I want only one error message and 3 yellow checkboxes. It this possible in JSF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has basically 2 solutions:

1. *Either* use a single [`<h:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html) instead of [`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectBooleanCheckbox.html)es, so that you can simply set `required="true"` on it:

   ```
   <h:selectManyCheckbox ... required="true">
       ...
   </h:selectManyCheckbox>
   ```
2. *Or* use [`<o:validateOneOrMore>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore) of [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org):

   ```
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="one" ... />
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="two" ... />
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="three" ... />
   <o:validateOneOrMore components="one two three" />
   ```